# Mobile Push Notifications Server Side Wrappers

Tags: c#, push-notification

We are just starting on mobile apps for our website for Windows 8, iPhone and Android.  I have been looking if there is already helper classes or server side wrappers for C# that implement all the basic functionality.

I found this library (WindowsPhone.Recipes.Push.Messasges) but I cannot find the source code as all the links appear to be broken.

Before I start work on writing our own wrappers for these I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the direction of some public implementations in C#.

Many thanks for any help, I've been searching like mad and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely have a look at [the PushSharp library](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp), which will be of good help for what you are trying to do.

[Here is a good presentation](http://fr.slideshare.net/Xamarin/push-notifications-introduction-to-pushsharp-seminar) by the library's author, and you can find some [quick-start  examples on GitHub](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp#some-sample-action).

There are more in-depth tutorials for [Apple Push Notification Service](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp) (iOS) and [Google Cloud Messaging](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-GCM-Google-Cloud-Messaging-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp) (Android) on the [GitHub PushSharp Wiki](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki).